# how to unzip same file name without override (capitalization differ)

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, zip, fat32

I have 2 files named xt_DSCP.h and xt_dscp.h in the same directory, in a zip file. I am trying to unzip them on my pendrive but I only have 2 options: skip or override.

I was searching for a solution but only found how to force override but I am actually trying to do the exact opposite.

File system is FAT32. I know that on NTFS it is not possible but FAT32 should allow it. I already unzipped the folder successfully in linux OS. Main goal is to use it in windows, however, which is why I am trying to pass it to pen drive on linux. Any attempt always resulted in overwritten files :(

can someone help?

Comment: FAT32 is not case-sensitive, thus you cannot have a file named `xt_DSCP.h` and `xt_dscp.h` in the same directory - both names describe the same file.

Comment: Would it be okay to extract these files to two different directories?

Comment: no, I must not change the file structure

Comment: Then you cannot use FAT32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are limited to just FAT32 and NTFS, then you cannot extract this archive and maintain both `xt_DSCP.h` and `xt_dscp.h` in the same directory - both names refer to the same file.

NTFS is aware of case (if you store files in upper case or lower case, this should persist), though you cannot store two files in a single directory whose names differ only in case.

There are options to mount ext filesystems on Windows, though I can't comment on how well this would work - it looks like standard Windows utilities like `explorer.exe` are unable to deal with this correctly.

The best solution would be to re-architect the project such that this doesn't happen.

Comment: FAT32 is not a requirement. WinOS is installed on NTFS so I'll stick with it. I'll see if I can mount ext4 or similar on windows but I doupt so. Project sources are not created by me not sure why it had been done this way. Last option I'll stick with linux.

Comment: If you're working on the linux kernel (as the name would suggest), then I'd strongly recommend sticking to linux anyway...